# value of $ (\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}xf(x)dx)^2$

Tags: definite-integrals

> Given $$ \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{tx}f(x)dx = \sin^{-1}\bigg(t-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg),$$
>
> then what is the value of $$ \bigg(\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}xf(x)dx\bigg)^2\quad ?$$

What I tried:

$$I(t)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{tx}f(x)dx=\sin^{-1}\bigg(t-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg)$$

$$I'(t)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{tx}tf(x)dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\bigg(t-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg)^2}}$$

I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Why are you squaring $dx$?

Comment: Verify your computation of $I^{\prime}(t)$ (you are differentiating with respect to $t$)

Comment: The $dx$ definitely shouldn't be squared. I suspect you don't want $f$ squared either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take derivative w.r.t. to $t$, then 
$$I'(t)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{tx}xf(x)dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\bigg(t-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg)^2}}.$$
Now simply let $t=0$.

Comment: This (Liebnitz integral rule,https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule ) is also called "Feynman's trick".